# Ruby on Rails Bundle Install Not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, rubygems

So I am currently learning Ruby on Rails using Michael Hartl tutorial (really noob at the moment - really new to programming). I have tried to edit the gemfiles in the "hello_app" that I am making - as told to do so by Michael, however when I go back into Terminal to run the bundle install - I get the following rather than it installing:

```
Abduls-MacBook-Pro:hello_app Monahim$ bundle install

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: unexpected fraction part after numeric literal -   gem 'sqlite3' , 1.3.12
                 ^
/Users/Monahim/railsmhartl/hello_app/Gemfile:40: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
gem 'byebug', '9.0.0' platform: :mri, end
                            ^
/Users/Monahim/railsmhartl/hello_app/Gemfile:55: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end. Bundler cannot continue.

 #  from /Users/Monahim/railsmhartl/hello_app/Gemfile:38
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  group :development, :test do
 >    gem 'sqlite3' , 1.3.12
#    # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
 #  -------------------------------------------
Abduls-MacBook-Pro:hello_app Monahim$
```

Can someone please let me know what is going on? And how do I fix it? Here's what I have in my Atom Text Editor:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "ht//githublinkhere /#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.4.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 3.0.0'
# See /githubrailsreadmelinkhere for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more:          /githubturbolinkhere
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5.0.1'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: linktojbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.4.1'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3' , 1.3.12
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.0' platform: :mri, 
end
# Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %>   anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.1.1'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.0.8'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: /github.com/railsspringlinkhere
  gem 'spring' , '1.7.2.'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Thank you very much for going through this.Please do explain what os going on so I learn as well as correcting the errors. Obviously you can tell I am really, really new to this game but am eager to learn!

Please advise,
Thanks!

Comment: Try this one, Define gem definition without giving versioning  `gem 'sqlite3'` in you `Gemfile`. or with giving versioning try this one `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two typos/errors in the `group :development, :test` from your `Gemfile`:

1. You are missing quotes (or double quotes) in your `sqlite3` gem version:

   ```
   gem 'sqlite3' , 1.3.12
                  ^      ^
   ```
2. There is a missing and trailing comma `,` in `gem 'byebug'`

   ```
   gem 'byebug', '9.0.0' platform: :mri,
                        ^              ^
   ```

So `group :development, :test` should look like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.12'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.0', platform: :mri 
end
```

Comment: It worked after using your edits and a bundle update. Thanks!

Comment: @abdulmuhaimen Great! Please don't forget to accept the answer (by clicking the green tick). Good luck!